Improving Polyline Accuracy and Display in Blazor WebAssembly with Leaflet.js Using MAUI-Captured Data
I'm developing a user tracking application using MAUI for capturing latitude and longitude data. This data is then displayed as a polyline using Leaflet.js in a Blazor WebAssembly application. However, I'm encountering some issues:
Accuracy: The captured latitude and longitude points sometimes have low accuracy, resulting in polylines that do not accurately represent the user's path.
Display: The polyline appears jagged and some points are displayed in incorrect locations, making the path look unrealistic.
Details:
Already tried Logic's:
OSRM API - http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/lon,lat?steps=false&geometries=geojson&overview=simplified&continue_straight=false
OpenRouteSerive - https://api.openrouteservice.org/v2/directions/driving-car/geojson
Environment:
MAUI: Used for capturing latitude and longitude data.
Blazor WebAssembly: For the front-end, displaying the map.
Leaflet.js: For rendering the map and polylines.
[Latitude and Longitude miss accuracy screenshot:


What's the reported accuracy (AKA "dilution of precision")? I'm referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.devices.sensors.location.accuracy?view=net-maui-8.0#microsoft-maui-devices-sensors-location-accuracy

@IvanSanchez - Thanks for the response
My inaccurate point's accuracy - 10.899999618530273 meters

And what's the actual error for that point? What's the distance between the reported position and the actual position?

more than 10 t0 20 meter
